# local storage repeating only last added array object on retrieval

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a JSON object (activityItem) that I add into an Array List(activityArrayList).

> var activityArrayList = [];
>
> var activityItem = {
>
> ```
>   activity_id: "" ,
>   activity_name: "",
>   item_viewed_time: null,
>   time_spent_on_item:0,
>   like: "didn't like or dislike",  
>
> };
> ```

I do this to add the list of activity items to local storage

```
    activityArrayList.push(activityItem);
    console.log(activityArrayList[0]);//see the item being added


      localStorage['ActivityArrayList'] = JSON.stringify(activityArrayList);
       var storedActivityList = (localStorage['ActivityArrayList']) ;

and in a new page in Jquery Mobile I have the following to retrieve the object

   var retrievedStringList = localStorage.getItem(['ActivityArrayList']); 
   var convertedList = JSON.parse(retrievedStringList);
   showitem(convertedList);


    function showitem(ItemsList){

          console.log(ItemsList);
    }
```

The console.log(ItemsList); function displays the correct number of items in the list(array size), but the item details are all the same, they are the details of the last added item to list.

[image]

2 different Activity items were added to the list, but it shows the details of the last item added twice.

Comment: It should be `localStorage.getItem('ActivityArrayList');`, although I don't think it makes any difference in this case. If you are using chrome, the developer can show the current contents of the localStorage. This should help you to narrow it down.

Comment: Your recipe seems incomplete. What happens is what I would expect to happen.

Comment: @sabof the console shows the last element that is being pushed to the array. and doing localStorage.getItem('ActivityArrayList'); doesnt make a difference. :/

Comment: Presumably, this code was in a loop, and there might have been other factors. Can you make a test case that show the error with multiple items?